# How to make SUBDIRS level defines visible in subprojects in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

The problem is as follows:

I have a folder that contains a bunch of library projects and 2 projects generating actual executables. Both **exe** projects utilize the libraries from that folder to do its stuff but otherwise are separate programs. So, I have two SUBDIRS projects in that folder.

```
super1.pro
super2.pro
```

Also, there is not a lot of that, but **some** code paths in libraries depend on the superproject that is actually being built. The dependency is resolved by adding this into the .cpp file

```
#ifdef SUPER1
```

So, what's the problem? The problem is that

```
DEFINES+=SUPER1
```

added in super1.pro will not be visible in subprojects and adding it into subprojects either directly or by means of .pri file fails to address the 
time when one will need to build the **other** project. It will have to be manual code change to **super2** then and this is just no good.

I have my solution to that problem below, but it just feels way too complex. If anyone has a better one that I am missing, please comment/answer.

Comment: qmake continues to regularly stump me, too. But it seems that maybe `.qmake.conf` is the tool that you are seeking? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html

Comment: I have since moved to using qbs. much better experience

Answer (score 1):

The basis for my solution is this post:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir

We first need to add a custom .pro file to the superproject parse order.
In super1.pro we add:

```
SUBDIRS += super1_DEFINES.pro sub1 sub2 sub3....
```

In super1_DEFINES.pro we write the following

```
TEMPLATE=subdirs
SUBDIRS= # don't build anything, we're just generating the .qmake.cache file
system(rm .qmake_cache.in)
system(cp .qmake.cache.super1 .qmake.cache.in)
QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES += .qmake.cache.in
```

what happens there, is that we utilise a system call to rewrite .qmake.cache.in placeholder file with the one specified by the the superproject *_DEFINES file. This rewritten file is then picked by the system and placed into builddir as .qmake.cache and, most importantly, DEFINES from that file **will** be picked by all the subprojects. .qmake.cache.super1 is actually just a simple .pro file which might look like this:

```
DEFINES += SOMEVARIABLE
```

when you want to build say, super42.pro you just use

```
SUBDIRS += super42_DEFINES.pro sub1 sub2 sub3....
```

and

```
system(cp .qmake.cache.super42 .qmake.cache.in)
```

and that's it. Like I said, the solution does seem too complex. I hope there is a better way, but this works for me so far.